# Can a UK permanent resident with Israeli passport enter Russia?

Tags: air-travel, uk-citizens, russia, covid-19, israeli-citizens

I have a dual citizenship - British and Israeli. I'm currently studying and living in the UK. I want to go to Russia to visit my family (I have some family which I haven't seen in a while).

Since there is no visa requirement for Israelis to enter Russia, can I travel with my Israeli passport to Russia? I do not want to pay for the visa for my English passport.

All Israelis (who are living in Israel) are banned from entering the country, but UK residents are not.

Is there any legal problem with what I want to do?

Comment: Possibly related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159743/travelling-from-uk-to-russia-with-israeli-passport

Comment: If you have family in Russia you should be able to travel ... perhaps. A fresh test would be required I assume.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass it is related (we're friends). Although mine is more detailed

Comment: @Marina, do not ask questions if you know they are already on the site. Better improve the existing question, (or ask your friend to include more details,) as we do not accept identical questions here. Your question is so close to the other one that at least one of them will get closed.

Comment: To be fair, the other question is pretty poor and should be closed as a dupe of this one...

Comment: @FreeMan if the friend doesn't have dual citizenship, it's not actually a duplicate (proof of residence tends to involve different evidence when it's a result of citzenship versus paperwork).

Comment: Unless you have a British residence permit in your Israeli passport, you are living in the United Kingdom as a British citizen as far as Russia is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Timatic's COVID travel information page](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php):

> 1. Passengers are not allowed to enter. This does not apply to:
>
> - nationals of the Russian Fed. and their family members;
> - permanent residents of the Russian Fed.;
> - British nationals and residents of the United Kingdom if arriving from the United Kingdom;

So you can indeed enter Russia at this time. You will use your British passport to prove you're a British national and then use your Israeli passport to gain visa-free entry. Showing two documents at once at immigration is common practice, so airline personnel shouldn't give you trouble for it. The Israeli passport will serve as an equivalent of a Russian visa, allowing you free passage.

**Update:** OP was able to travel successfully:

> @JonathanReez it worked! They asked me for both passports both times, just like you said, and it all went without any disturbances!

Comment: *Showing two documents at once at immigration is common practice,...*: without reliable sources confirming this to be generally true, caution should be taken with this advice. As a mixture (that applies basically to dual citizens only) of immigration and health regulations, there is no guarantee how an immigration officer may react. An Airline, which may be fined, may come to a more cautious conclusion.

Comment: @MarkJohnson if your interpretation was correct, Timatic would say something like "British nationals with a Russian visa in their British passport", not just "British nationals". They work hard to make sure that they're as specific as possible.

Comment: The quote refers to the **COVID-19 Travel Regulations**, not to the Visa requirements.

Comment: @MarkJohnson that is correct. COVID regulations are on top of regular visa regulations. In this particular scenario the British passport satisfies the COVID part and the Israeli passport satisfies the Visa part.

Comment: I will check whether your answer is correct on sunday morning :) really hope it is. I will show my british passport and israeli passport as you said

Comment: @Marina just make sure you have a PCR test on hand too!

Comment: @JonathanReez it worked! They asked me for both passports both times, just like you said, and it all went without any disturbances!